# jquery scrollable to same panel if not validate

Tags: php, scrollable

I am hoping someone can help me with the following:

I have a jquery scrollable on a page where on the third scrollable panel there is a form.

I am validating the form fields with jquery but also with php. The problem is that when validating on the server (with php) the page is refershed and the first panel is shown instread fo the third.

Is there any way to make sure the same third panel with the form will be shown after server validation?

Sorry hope my question is clear. Any little help will be much appreciated. F

Answer (score 0):

You should, in your form action, add an anchor at the end of your URL, for example.

```
action="submit.php#panel_3"
```

The next step would be to implement an event when your jquery is loading, to focus on the third panel, according the hash "panel_3", set in the url.